# Content Security Policy Blocking Links from CodePen to Github

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, codepen

In my project some people are getting a Content Security Error which is blocking them from accessing the links in the viewer. The page will load and grab the data and display it but when they click on a link it will give the error. See the screenshot for error messages. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Code:

```
<script>
        window.API = {
          fetchPopularRepos(language) {
            // "language" can be "javascript", "ruby", "python", or "all"
            const encodedURI = encodeURI(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:${language}&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories`)
            return fetch(encodedURI)
              .then((data) => data.json())
              .then((repos) => repos.items)
              .catch((error) => {
                console.warn(error)
                return null
              });
          }
        }
</script>
```

[CORS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo54V.png)

Project is here: https://codepen.io/tmstani23/pen/vjqwKJ?editors=1011

Comment: Have you read up on the errors you get? For example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I've read on it a little but I'm not sure how to circumvent this in this instance.  Other than perhaps using a different method to get the data.  Also part of the problem is that I don't have the issue accessing the links only some other people who use the site.

Comment: Can someone please verify that this is an issue.  Some people are saying they can access the links.  If you cannot please add a screenshot or error message to this post.  Thanks.